# Change locale for JUnit tests via Spring context

Tags: spring, junit, gradle

All tests are launched by gradle.
I'd like to define the locale for all JUnit tests on a project. At first I thought about the following way:

```
public class TestCases {
    static Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setDefaultLocale() {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK);
    }

    // here goes bunch of tests
    // ...

    @AfterClass
    public static void restoreLocale() {
        Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);
    }
}
```

But it is too cumbersome, as I have hundreds of files to be changed. 
I found also that running single test with `-Duser.language=en` parameter (I use Intellij) will do the job.  But I am not able to change gradle scripts in order to provide this solution.
Is there any way to define Locale for JUnit tests via Spring context? Or maybe there is an other better way? Thanks.

Comment: One improvement, albeit not a solution, is to declare a parent test class that sets the locale and have all your relevant tests extend that.

Comment: Thanks, this could work. But still looks cumbersome for me as the locale is changed twice for each test class. Or it's looks so just for me?

Comment: You can provide the system property on the command line for Gradle as well: `gradle -Duser.language=en test`.

Comment: The tests are launched by gradle wrapper, I think it doesn't support this way of setting parameters. Tests still failing because of wrong locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to add a test lifecycle hook that is fired before your suite is executed.

```
test.beforeSuite { TestDescriptor suite ->
   System.setProperty('user.language', 'en')
}
```

Comment: As I said, unfortunately, I can not change gradle scripts

Comment: Can you please give refs or something about TestDescriptor that you mentioned?

Comment: The class [TestDescriptor](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestDescriptor.html) is described in the Gradle API.